# Using SvnKit and Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, svnkit

Is there a way to get Netbeans 6.7/8 to work with SVNkit?

I'm looking for a plugin to replace the built-in SVN Netbeans plugin or a similiar solution.  Right now, my workaround is to make copies of all of the jsvn commands and rename the copies to the svn equivalent.  It works, but its a headache.

Edit:  As to why I want to do this, its to make possible Eclipse and Netbeans sharing a single project instance on a linux box.  On Windows, it doesn't matter because Eclipse can use the javahl to access svn.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to reinstall Fedora this last time, I've changed from making copies of the shell scripts to making soft links to them so that the names work.

Then I tell Netbeans to use that svnkit directory as SVN_HOME.   It solves the problem, but its only slightly better than the copies routine.

Comment: I'm sorry to comment so old question.  But could you please show how to "tell NetBeans to use SVN_HOME"? Thanks.